# libPhonenumber (from Google) on iOS in a Kotlin Native project

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-native

I've been struggling to solve a problem.

I'm building a cross platform app (iOS and Android) using Kotlin Multiplatform (KMP) where I need a library from Google (https://github.com/google/libphonenumber).

For Android, I can point to a Maven repo (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/googlecode/libphonenumber/libphonenumber/8.12.6/).

For iOS, I can use a ObjC port of libPhonenumber via Cocoapods.(https://cocoapods.org/pods/libPhoneNumber-ios).

But, I can't use Kotlin's (cocoapod plugin) to properly recognize the Pod.  The plugin appears to fail to build.
Here's the details of my setup:

1. Xcode v11.5
2. IntelliJ IDEA v2020.1.2
3. Cocoapods v1.9.1
4. Gradle 6.0.1
5. Sample repo (https://github.com/touchlab/kotlin-native)
   NOTE: Within the repo, I'm using ./samples/cocoapods
6. modify ./samples/cocoapods/kotlin-library/build.gradle.kts
   commented out AFNetworking, remove AFNetworking pod
   `pod("AFNetworking", "~> 3.2.0")`
   add a new pod
   `pod("libPhoneNumber-iOS")`
7. modify ./samples/cocoapods/kotlin-library/gradle.properties
   change this line:
   `kotlin.native.home=../../../dist`
   to this:
   `#kotlin.native.home=../../../dist`
8. in Terminal in this folder: ./samples/cocoapods/kotlin-library/
   `./gradlew podspec`
   This creates a podspec file (libPhoneNumber-iOS.def) in ./samples/cocoapods/kotlin-library/build/cocoapods/defs/
9. cd from kotlin-library to ios-app folder
   `cd ../ios-app/`
10. Pod install using the command:
    `pod install`
    You'll see something like:

```
Downloading dependencies
Installing kotlin_library (1.0)
Installing libPhoneNumber-iOS (0.9.15)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
Pod installation complete! There is 1 dependency from the Podfile and 2 total pods installed.
```

When I build the sample 'ios-app' target: simulator in Xcode, I get the error:
`fatal error: module 'libPhoneNumber' not found`

I have tried other libPhoneNumber pods, such as:

- libPhoneNumberSwift
- LTPhoneNumberField
  Both fail to build using Kotlin's cocoapods plugin, but work as a Pod without Kotlin's cocoapod plugin.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This particular problem seems to be caused by the dash in the pod's name. There was already an issue reported [on GitHub](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-native/issues/2884). For now, it's recommended to workaround this problem by re-naming the module. Changing your `kotlin-library/build.gradle.kts` like

```
 pod("libPhoneNumber-iOS", moduleName = "libPhoneNumber_iOS")
```

should help. Please give it a try and tell here or on GH if it works.

Answer (score 0):

I have obtained excellent results by adding the unchanged Javascript version of libphonenumber using JavaScriptCore in IOS. The only part of the library not available yet in Javascript is the geocoder.
I used the concept explained here: https://www.appcoda.com/javascriptcore-swift .
Performance is great and there is no porting involved. Always the latest version available.