# Adding CocoaPod to KMM project

Tags: cocoapods, kotlin-multiplatform

I'm trying to add a pod to a KMM project but can't get it working properly. The pod in question is libPhoneNumber-iOS (https://github.com/iziz/libPhoneNumber-iOS)

If I add the pod to my podfile, everything builds file and I can access the library within the xCode project. However, the c-interop isn't created and I can't access the library from within shared>iOSMain - which I need!

If I add the pod to the cocoapods block in my shared build.gradle.kts file, the c-interop is generated and I can access the library from within shared>iOSMain. However, the xCode project won't build. I get hundreds of errors - anything that uses shared cannot be found.

Following various answers to other questions, I've tried:

- xCode 14.3 and 15
- AS Giraffe and Hedgehog (RC1)
- Adding via both cocoapod block and pod file

Any thoughts on what I need to do to get this library working?

---

**Update**

I've managed to work around this by creating an interface on the KMM side, a class that implements the interface on the Swift side, and then passing that class from Swift to Kotlin during app start up.

This completely circumvents having to get any Swift/Objective-C code running in Kotlin.

I would still love to know why I couldn't get it working properly using the pod in KMM so leaving the question open, but for now at least, I've managed to get what I needed working, and wanted to share mysolution for anyone who finds this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [libPhonenumber (from Google) on iOS in a Kotlin Native project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62736425/libphonenumber-from-google-on-ios-in-a-kotlin-native-project)

Comment: Unfortunately not - I'd already tried that but it didn't make a difference. It looks like something got changed and the "-" is now being changed to a "_" automatically.